# how to make an executable file targeting macOS which is simple console app written in c#?

Tags: c#, macos, file, unix, mkbundle

I want to make an executable file targeting macOS that runs without the need for a mono framework or other runtimes for it to run. The executable file that I want to create is written in C# using visual studio for Mac. I managed to build it with mkbundle, it runs on my system of macOS but when a run it on another Mac without mono runtime it ends with this error:

> Unhandled exception.... but the console app I made runs without
> problem on my Mac...

can anyone help me?

Comment: Sounds like you want to make a statically linked binary. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://github.com/Cryru/The-Struggles-Of-Running-And-Statically-Linking-Mono ?

Comment: I have tried to do it with mkbuild, but the executable file it created does not contain the dependencies and did not run on another Mac without any framework or runtime (although it run on mine) I want to make my console app Witten in c# to be self-contained unix executable file is there a way to do that? thanks for your concern...